# System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'EmpID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I've tried to execute a post method but I'm receiving this error continuously.

```
Exception : System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'EmpID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Demo.Controllers.EmployeeController.GetEmployeeDetails1(EmployeeDetails id) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Demo\Demo\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 53
```

My Json Input for Posting Through "PostMan":

```json
{
  "FirstName": "x",
  "LastName": "y",
  "Status": "Active",
  "Age": 20,
  "Designation": "Trainee",
  "Salary": 15000,
  "DoorNo": "153",
  "StreetName": "G block",
  "Area": "Anna Nagar",
  "City": "Chennai",
  "State": "Tamilnadu",
  "ContactNo": 9876543210,
  "EmailID": "priyaflorentzcharls@gmailcom",
  "Qualification": "BE",
  "Experience": 0,
  "FormerCompany": "NA",
  "AwardsAndTitles": "NA"
}
```

This is my controller:

```cs
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    public readonly EmployeeDataContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [Route("AddEmployee")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EmployeeDet>>> GetEmployeeDetails1([FromBody] EmployeeDetails id)
    {

        try
        {
            var StoredProc = "EXEC PROC_INSERTEMPLOYEEDETAILS " +
                "@FirstName =" + id.FirstName + ", "+
                "@LastName =" + id.LastName + ", "+
                "@Status =" + id.Status + ", "+
                "@Age =" + id.Age + ", "+
                "@Designation =" + id.Designation + ", "+
                "@Salary =" + id.Salary + ", " +
                "@DoorNo =" + id.DoorNo + ", " +
                "@StreetName =" + id.StreetName + ", " +
                "@Area =" + id.Area + ", " +
                "@City =" + id.City + ", " +
                "@State =" + id.State + ", " +
                "@ContactNo =" + id.ContactNo + ", " +
                "@EmailID =" + id.EmailID + ", " +
                "@Qualification =" + id.Qualification + ", " +
                "@Experience =" + id.Experience + ", " +
                "@FormerCompany =" + id.FormerCompany + ", " +
                "@AwardsAndTitles =" + id.AwardsAndTitles;

            await _context.EmployeeDetails.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync();
            return await _context.EmployeeDetails.FromSqlRaw("Select Top 1 FROM EmployeeDetails order by EmpID Desc").ToListAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok("Exception : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My Stored Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROC PROC_INSERTEMPLOYEEDETAILS
            (
            @FirstName varchar(100),
            @LastName  varchar(100),
            @Status varchar(25),
            @Age int,
            @Designation varchar(50),
            @Salary decimal, 
            @DoorNo varchar(20), 
            @StreetName varchar(200),
            @Area varchar(200), 
            @City varchar(100),
            @State varchar(50),
            @ContactNo BIGINT,
            @EmailID varchar(50),
            @Qualification varchar(100),
            @Experience int,
            @FormerCompany varchar(100),
            @AwardsAndTitles varchar(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @EmpID varchar(25), @Address varchar(200);
            SET @EmpID = CONCAT('KZNJ', 01 , NEXT VALUE FOR seq_count)
            SET @Address = CONCAT(@DoorNo, ' , ', @StreetName, ' , ', @Area, ' , ', @City, ' , ', @State)
            INSERT INTO EmployeeMaster
                        (
                        EmpID, 
                        FirstName,
                        LastName,
                        [Status],
                        Age,
                        Designation,
                        Salary
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                        @EmpID, 
                        @FirstName,
                        @LastName,
                        @Status,
                        @Age,
                        @Designation,
                        @Salary
                        )
            INSERT INTO AddressOfEmployee
                        (
                        EmpID, 
                        DoorNo, 
                        StreetName,
                        Area, 
                        City,
                        [State]
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                        @EmpID, 
                        @DoorNo, 
                        @StreetName,
                        @Area, 
                        @City,
                        @State
                        )
            INSERT INTO ContactsOfEmployee
                        (
                        EmpID, 
                        [Address],
                        ContactNo,
                        EmailID
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                        @EmpID,
                        @Address, 
                        @ContactNo,
                        @EmailID
                        )
            INSERT INTO QualificationExps
                        (
                        EmpID, 
                        Qualification,
                        Experience,
                        FormerCompany,
                        AwardsAndTitles
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                        @EmpID, 
                        @Qualification,
                        @Experience,
                        @FormerCompany,
                        @AwardsAndTitles
                        )           
    COMMIT TRANSACTION      
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'Error' = @@ERROR
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                
        END     
END CATCH
```

Here is my Model for receiving inputs:

```cs
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    [Key]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string EmpID;
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string DoorNo { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Int64 ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public string FormerCompany { get; set; }
    public string AwardsAndTitles { get; set; }

    //public List<EmployeeDetails> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Since I had computed the value for "EmpID", I haven't inserted but showing like this wasting my time as a fresher struggling with this.

I've tried to execute a post method but I'm receiving this error continuously.
Expecting to insert the values in the table I have created.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Try to remove  [JsonIgnore] attribute before the EmpID property of the EmployeeDetails model class

Comment: You didn'T say where you get that exception in your code. "Select Top 1 FROM EmployeeDetail" looks like illegal syntax. You must define what columns to return. And you try to return something called "EmployeeDet". Typo or a type you forgot to show?

Comment: Calling `FromSqlRaw` to execute a Stored Proc that does not return anything feels also wrong.

Comment: Why are not using using `XACT_ABORT` in the above, and why *`SELECT`* the error rather than let it just be `THROWN`.

Comment: This means that the column 'EmpID' is not being returned in the result set. Try to use `[NotMapped]` attribute with 'EmpID'.

Comment: @Chen I've tried  NotMapped or JsonIgnore too Nothing Fruitful Sir since it is primary key i couldnt execute using these. repeatedly showing the EmpID missing and if i managed to get rid of this the Error is jumping to "Age" is Missing!

Comment: The error is at " await _context.EmployeeDetails.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync();" @Ralf

Comment: Your stored proc does not return anything but FromSqlRaw will try to map that to a EmployeeDetails. Its meant for querying. Look at `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`for a more fitting method to execute your stored proc.